# Obtener valores de res.locals en otro midleware

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy tratando de lograr que la pagina renderize la información de un usuario que esta almacenada en `res.locals`, sin embargo el router al render esta en otro archivo, por ende no puedo lograr que acceda a la información de `res.locals`.

```js
// root.js

var express    =require('express');
var router_app =require('./modulos/rutas');
var web        =express();  

web.use('/dashboard',router_app);

web.post('/login',function(entra,sale){ //AQUI INICIA EL LOGIN 
 valida.logIn(user).then((user)=>{
    //Tiene que estar dentro de esta promesa puesto que tiene 
    //Guardar la informacion que retorna de esta promesa
  sale.locals = {user : "Informacion Aqui"};
    //Hasta aqui recibe bien la informacion

  sale.redirect('/dashboard');
 }).catch((error)=>{
  console.log("Rechazado"+error);
 });
});
```

Hasta aqui vamos bien.

```js
//rutas.js

var express=        require('express');
var router =  express.Router();

router.get('/',(entra,sale)=>{

 console.log(sale.locals);
 //Aqui no imprime nada, la informacion ya no esta
});


module.exports = router;
```

Aquí ya no me imprime nada la consola, simplemente la información que guarde antes en el `locals`, no esta...
La idea que guardar en `locals` el id de un usuario para poder buscar la información de dicho usuario y rende-rizar la pagina con toda la información bajada de la `BD` respecto al usuario. Ya tengo algo de tiempo investigando sobre la `res.locals` y aun no he llegado a la solución de este problema.

Estaba leyendo que tiene que ver con que `.render` llama a `.end` y por eso se elimina la información del `.locals`.

Answer (score 2):

`res.locals` sólo existe [durante el presente request](http://expressjs.com/es/api.html#res.locals)

> An object that contains response local variables scoped to the
>   request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered during
>   that request

`app.locals` persiste [en todo el ciclo de vida de la aplicación](http://expressjs.com/es/api.html#app.locals)

> Once set, the value of app.locals properties persist throughout the
>   life of the application

Por lo tanto lo que quieres hacer debiera ser como sigue:

```
app.post('/login',function(req, res){  
    valida.logIn(user).then((user)=>{
        req.app.locals = {user : "Informacion Aqui"};
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log("Rechazado"+error);
    });
});
```

Y luego:

```
router.get('/',(req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.app.locals);
});
```

Me queda la duda acerca del nombre de la propiedad `entra.app`. Según yo, no importa que hayas declarado la app como `web`, debiera accederse igual y no como `entra.web`. Pero si no te resulta lo primero, prueba lo segundo.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses passport, o al menos le eches un vistazo a express-session y como mantener las sessiones persistentes entre requests

https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session

Este es un ejemplo de express-session

```
// Use the session middleware
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))

// Access the session as req.session
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.views) {
    req.session.views++
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    res.write('<p>views: ' + req.session.views + '</p>')
    res.write('<p>expires in: ' + (req.session.cookie.maxAge / 1000) + 's</p>')
    res.end()
  } else {
    req.session.views = 1
    res.end('welcome to the session demo. refresh!')
  }
})
```